# Missing return Statement in for loop

Tags: java

I am trying to make a dynamic 2D (nxn)matrix with ascending numbers;
Ex: 1 2 3 4 
    5 6 7 8
    n n n n
    n n n n

At compilation it gives me the error "Missing Return Statment".

```
import javax.swing.*;
public class Hw4ex2{
    public static void main(String args[]){

    String a = JOptionPane.showInputDialog ("Matrix size nxn");
    int size = Integer.parseInt(a);

}
}       


    public static int[][] matrix1(int size){

    int[][] matrix1 = new int[size][size];
    int x = 1;

    for(int i=0; i<size; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<size; j++){
            matrix1[i][j] = x;
            x++;

            System.out.print(matrix1[i][j]);
        }
    }   

}
```

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: What in particular about the error message is confusing you? It seems quite clear, to me.

Comment: Add a `return` statement or change your function's result type to `void`. Also, you probably need to call the function at some point in `main` if you want to see any results.

Comment: It gives you this error because return statement is really missing.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a return statement to the method `matrix1`.

So for example, write this under the for:

```
return matrix1;
```

Please use indentations to make your code look more beautiful and more clear.
You defined the function `matrix1` outside of a class, so your code won't work.
Also consider to look at a Java Hello World Tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

In order to return a value from a Java method you must execute a `return` statement with the value as operand. It is not enough to name a variable the same as the method.

Answer (score 0):

You've told Java that you'll be returning a double matrix of type int: `int[][]` when you declared the method: `public static **int[][]** matrix1(int size){`

Either:

a) Return a double array of type int

```
public static int[][] matrix1(int size){

int[][] matrix1 = new int[size][size];
int x = 1;

  for(int i=0; i<size; i++){
      for(int j=0; j<size; j++){
          matrix1[i][j] = x;
          x++;
          System.out.print(matrix1[i][j]);
      }
  }   
return matrix1; //<-- return the thing you promised!
}
```

b) Return nothing: public static **void** matrix1(int size){

Since it seems you're just trying to print out the values in the 2D array, you probably don't need to return anything (go with choice b)